# How to convert Json to Java Object, Deserializing Json

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization

```
data_user = "{"id":1,"lastName":"lastName","name":"name","school":{"id":1}}"

public class School {
     private int id;
     private String name;
}

public class User {
     private int id;
     private String lastName;
     private String name;
     private School school;
}
```

How to deserialize Json data_user to java object User?

I tried with Gson :

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 User user = gson.fromJson(data_user, User.class)
```

But I have an error with this code because the Json contains a school which hasn't the school's name.

How Can I serialize the Json to java Object?

Comment: What's your error? Provide your stack trace.

Comment: One error (compile) is the string for `data_user` is missing some ` \ ` . Another error (runtime) is that `User` does not have a `school` member, but it does have a `country`(?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**School.java**

```
public class School {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "School [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String lastName;
    private String name;
    private School school;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public School getSchool() {
        return school;
    }
    public void setSchool(School school) {
        this.school = school;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", name=" + name
                + ", school=" + school + "]";
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.testgson.beans.User;

public class Main {
    private static Gson gson;

    static {
        gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String j = "{\"id\":1,\"lastName\":\"lastName\",\"name\":\"ignacio\",\"school\":{\"id\":1}}";
        User u = gson.fromJson(j, User.class);
        System.out.println(u);
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
User [id=1, lastName=lastName, name=ignacio, school=School [id=1, name=null]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the Jackson Library. With Gson with should have not any problem, I tried with the code of @Saurabh and it work well